# How to avoid expensive array marshalling between VBA and C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, com, marshalling

I'm exporting this C# method through COM:

```cs
public interface IMatrixMath {
    void AddScaledRange3D(ref double[,,] acc, [In] ref double[,,] vals, double scale);
    // ...
}
```

Then I call it with large matrices from VBA in Excel:

```vb
Dim A(0 To 2000, 0 To 120, 0 To 500) As Double
Dim B(0 To 2000, 0 To 120, 0 To 500) As Double
' ...
MatrixMath.AddScaledRange3D A, B, 0.4
```

This takes about 15 seconds but only 1 second of that time is spent in C#. Most of it is overhead *before* entering the C# method.

I'm not sure where the overhead comes from. If Excel needs to marshal to SAFEARRAY, wouldn't it need to marshal back, too? Why does it even take so long, doesn't Excel store arrays contiguously? Could it be related to crossing certain COM boundaries?

Are there ways around this overhead? I don't mind dealing with raw pointers or non-COM interop.

Comment: Is the COM object out of process or in process with Excel?

Comment: Should be in-process, and I think it is since I can attach to Excel and hit breakpoints in the C# code.

Comment: Yes if you hit bp in your code when debugging the excel process, you're in-process. There can  be marshaling (serialization cost) if your object is not accessed in the same COM apartment than the caller. Normally, .NET COM object can be access from any apartment in a free-threaded manner (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-and-unmanaged-threading-in-windows). But, that's something you could look at, check if anything was changed from default setup.